# seaborn countplot with top five count

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Given this code, I have like 200 different `RetentionAge` , it makes the graph is difficult to read:

```
sns.countplot(x='CPU', hue="RetentionAge", data=dfCombined_df)
```

[image]

Is there a way to select the top five count Offline_RetentionAge so the graph looks better?

Answer (score 1):

You can try separating your `hue` values into classes using a `facet grid` which would enable you to retain all your values and visually display them better.

[Facet Grid](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)